# Hidden jquery.elastic textarea doesn't expand properly

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using [Elastic](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) with a textarea that's loaded within a hidden container. When it's displayed, entering text causes it to grow each time I add a character. I think it has to do with the hidden textarea having no width defined. I tried adding a call to setTwinWidth() within the update() function. It worked, but IE7 & IE8 started throwing "stack overflow" and "out of memory" errors. Then I realized that with my change, both functions were now calling each other over and over.

Any idea why [setTwinWidth()](http://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js) needs to call update()?

Any clues on how to fix the plug-in (see fiddle below)?

[Hidden Elastic Test - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjens/svXEL/3/)

Following code is from jsFiddle. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me submit the question with the jsFiddle but without some code (seems weird). It's not really relevant

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('textarea').elastic();

    $('button').click(function() {
       $('#rowHidden').toggle(); 
    });    
});
```

I've tried contacting the author but heard nothing back.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just hide the textarea after things have been initialized instead of via the css like this - http://jsfiddle.net/svXEL/5/ ?  That seems to function correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('textarea').elastic();

    $('button').click(function() {
       $('#rowHidden').toggle(); 
    });    

    $('#rowHidden').hide();
});
```